# CryptographicBuffer equivalent in .Net Standard?

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-standard

I'm trying to migrate a couple of cryptographic functions that I had in WinRT like:

```
CryptographicBuffer.GenerateRandom(256);
```

I'm trying to find a similar function in .net Core or .net Standard but cannot find it. Does anybody know if there is a equivalent function or do I have to build my own?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` class is probably what you are looking for.

Example usage:

```
System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider Crypto;
Crypto = new System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider();

byte[] Buffer = new byte[256];
Crypto.GetBytes(Buffer);
```

This will fill the buffer with random data.  To change the amount of data, change the size of the buffer array.

Reference [RNGCryptoServiceProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider?view=netframework-4.8) documentation:

> Implements a cryptographic Random Number Generator (RNG) using the
>   implementation provided by the cryptographic service provider (CSP).